# Mission Control erratic behavior

Tags: mission-control

Whenever I minimize a maximized application window (e.g., MS Word) in a Desktop Space, the computer:

1. Moves the application window to a different Desktop Space, and
2. Either:

   1. closes the Desktop Space, or
   2. Doesn't close the Desktop Space, leaving it empty.

I've deselected automatic rearrangement and the option about switching to a Space with that application when opening an application.

I would like to be able to minimize an application window and have it stay in the same Desktop Space. It would be nice to be able to close it and have the focus stay in the same (now empty) Desktop Space.

Comment: It depends on whether the app you maximised moves to a new desktop or not. See for two contrasting apps. @marc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Is "move to a new desktop when minimized" expected behavior from an app?

Comment: No, moving to a new desktop when maximised is expected to almost all apps. And coming back to original after coming to normal mode too.

Comment: Do you mean minimise a **maximised** window, or do you mean minimise a **fullscreen** window? Mission Control will never automatically remove a Space created manually, but it will always add & remove fullscreen Spaces whenever it needs. There is nothing "behind" a fullscreen window, so if you do manage to minimise it [you shouldn't be able to but Word may have its own behaviour] then idk what would happen.

Comment: This is what I mean:

I create a new space.

I open an application window in it. 

I maximize it (press the green button).

I work in it. I finish. 

I press the green button again to "un-maximize" it. 

The application window moves to a different space. The original space is now empty.

Comment: What you are seeing is expected behaviour. The green button doesn't maximise, it fullscreens. Fullscreen apps get their own new Space, when you return from fullscreen that new Space disappears again, leaving you with the one you created but never used. If you started with multiple app windows in different Spaces, they will always try to return to the 'main' Space for that app. Apps don't like to be spread over different Spaces.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. That explains it. I guess I'll just have to go with yabai.